# postconf -e postfix_mydestination = localhost blah.deblah.com.au

Tags: postfix

Above is example of command someone used to successfully direct to subdomain but when I try it I get `postconf: fatal: missing '=' after attribute name` which makes no sense to me when clearly the equal sign is there.

Comment: Are there spaces in your command line around the equal sign? Seems to me that there must not be spaces.

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
postconf -e "postfix_mydestination = localhost, blah.deblah.com.au"
```

Note the quotes and the comma (it's comma separated). Also note you're not editing the main `mydestination` here, but the `postfix_` instance one. Not sure if that's what you actually want.

You need quoting because of the witespace around the equal sign. Just read from the manpage `postconf(1)`:

```
-e     Edit  the main.cf configuration file, and update parameter settings with
       the "name=value" pairs on the postconf(1)  command  line.  The  file  is
       copied  to  a temporary file then renamed into place.  Specify quotes to
       protect special characters and whitespace  on  the  postconf(1)  command
       line.
```

Comment: does this make it so directed at subdomain?

Comment: because in main.cf the hostname had to put main domain because that is what som1 told me in here to do or rather they said use destination for subdomains

Comment: don't i need a db before anything will work? omg they need simple tutorials and not entire novels to read on this

Comment: that syntax worked thanks but have no idea what it did- how can I test mail in command line?

Comment: The values you put in `mydestination` are the recipient domains it will accept for a local transport. Read manpages, practice with tutorials and learn. This is really basic Postfix configuration. In large virtual domain/alias setups a database might be nice, but start using plain configuration files is my suggestion.

Comment: can you please rephrase that? i know what a recipient is but i'm unclear what you mean ..